# Do all decidable problems lie in the class NP?

Tags: undecidability, np

All decision problems (i.e.language membership problems), which are verifiable in polynomial time by a deterministic Turing machine are called NP problems. Further, these problems can be solved by a non-deterministic Turing machine in a polynomial time and in exponential time by a deterministic Turing machine.

Do we have a decision problem that is not verifiable by a deterministic Turing machine in polynomial time but decidable?

Comment: [This seems related](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/3402), specifically "The most important thing to realize from a theoretical standpoint is that NP is actually a relatively small class of all decidable languages".

Answer (score 5):

No to the question in your title; yes to the question in the body of your post.

By the [non-deterministic time hierarchy theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_hierarchy_theorem#Non-deterministic_time_hierarchy_theorem), every decidable [NEXP-hard decision problem](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/3297) is "a decision problem that is not verifiable by a deterministic Turing machine in polynomial time but decidable".

Comment: Explanation of edit: the restriction to *decidable* NEXP-hard problems is required because the halting problem is NEXP-hard but is not "a decision problem that is not verifiably by a deterministic polytime TM but decidable."

Comment: Ah, yes. $\;\;$

Answer (score 0):

A concrete counterexample could be [Quantifed Boolean Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantified_boolean_formula), which is only verifiable in polynomial time if PSPACE=P. There's a whole myriad of other examples. You might also want to look at [coNP-complete](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CoNP) problems. For these a polynomial TM can only verify counterexamples (unless coNP=NP). The language of all tautologies is a prominent example for that class.

Comment: Why give a conditional example (i.e., one that relies on some conjecture about complexity classes) when there are so many unconditional ones?

Comment: @DavidRicherby  Because I find those problems a lot more intuitive than many of the NEXP-problems, and I think that at least PSPACE $\neq$ P is not the weirdest thing to assume. But OK, I get your point. I'll change my answer accordingly.