# are all problems in P in NP

Tags: np

I know this is a similar question to this [post](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/26042/do-all-decidable-problems-lie-in-the-class-np), but I want to further clarify my understanding.
In the picture from wikipedia: [image]

I understand that every problem that's in $P$ is also in NP.
does this mean that everything from MergeSort, to linear search is in NP [though not NP-HARD]? Or does this only apply to decision problems [aka YES, NO].

But then is it possible to turn any problem that is solvable in less than exponential time into a problem in $P$, hence a problem in $NP$?

thanks!

Comment: [Our reference question on P and NP](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/9556/) provides a basic, but thorough introduction to the topic, which includes an answer to the question in your title.

Comment: As for your final question, note that "less than exponential" can still be "more than polynomial" (although it depends a bit on the precise definitions involved)

Comment: Thanks @Discretelizard, That's helpful and I see in your link that P is a subset of NP